# Does perf lock profile user space mutexes?

Tags: linux, perf

**Summary**: Does `perf lock` profile pthread_mutex?

**Details**:

The tool `perf` has an option `perf lock`.  The man page says:

```
You can analyze various lock behaviours and statistics with this perf lock command.
   'perf lock record <command>' records lock events
    between start and end <command>. And this command
    produces the file "perf.data" which contains tracing
    results of lock events.

    'perf lock trace' shows raw lock events.

    'perf lock report' reports statistical data.
```

But when I tried running `perf lock record` I got an error saying: `invalid or unsupported event: 'lock:lock_acquire'`.  I looked and it seems that error is probably because my kernel is not compiled with `CONFIG_LOCKDEP` or `CONFIG_LOCK_STAT`.

My question is: does `perf lock` report events related to user-space locks (like pthread_mutex) or only kernel locks?  I'm more interested in profiling application that mostly run in user-space.  I thought this option in perf looked interesting, but since I can't run it without compiling (or getting) a new kernel I'm interested in getting a better idea of what it does before I try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Summary: Does perf lock profile pthread_mutex?

Summary: no, because there are no any tracepoint defined in user-space pthread_mutex.

According to source file `tools/perf/builtin-lock.c` (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/builtin-lock.c#L939) `cmd_lock` calls  `__cmd_record`, which defines several tracepoints for `perf record` (via `-e TRACEPOINT_NAME`) and also pass options `-R -m 1024 -c 1` to `perf report`. List of tracepoints defined: [`lock_tracepoints`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=lock_tracepoints):

```
842 static const struct perf_evsel_str_handler lock_tracepoints[] = {
843         { "lock:lock_acquire",   perf_evsel__process_lock_acquire,   }, /* CONFIG_LOCKDEP */
844         { "lock:lock_acquired",  perf_evsel__process_lock_acquired,  }, /* CONFIG_LOCKDEP, CONFIG_LOCK_STAT */
845         { "lock:lock_contended", perf_evsel__process_lock_contended, }, /* CONFIG_LOCKDEP, CONFIG_LOCK_STAT */
846         { "lock:lock_release",   perf_evsel__process_lock_release,   }, /* CONFIG_LOCKDEP */
847 };
```

`TRACE_EVENT(lock_acquire,..` is defined in  `trace/events/lock.h`. And
`trace_lock_acquire` is defined only in kernel/locking/lockdep.c (recheck in debian codebase: http://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=trace_lock_acquire). 
Only CONFIG_LOCKDEP is missing from your kernel according to `kernel/locking/Makefile`: `obj-$(CONFIG_LOCKDEP) += lockdep.o` (tracepoints are defined unconditionally in the `lockdep.c`.

According to https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/tracepoints.txt all tracepoints are kernel-only, so `perf lock` will not profile user-space locks.

You can try tracepoints from LTTng, the project which declares user-space tracepoints (http://lttng.org/ust). But there will be no ready lock statistics, only raw data on tracepoints. Also you should define tracepoints with `tracef()` macro (recompile pthreads/glibc, or try to create your own wrapper around pthread).

Comment: "tracepoints are kernel-only", but there are uprobes to be profiled with perf - http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2015-06-28/linux-ftrace-uprobe.html and https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.17/trace/uprobetracer.html

Answer (score 1):

No. But maybe what you need can be done by recording sched_stat_sleep and sched_switch events:

```
$ perf record -e sched:sched_stat_sleep,sched:sched_switch -g -o perf.data.raw yourprog
$ perf inject -v -s -i perf.data.raw -o perf.data
$ perf report --stdio --no-children
```

Note: make sure your kernel is compiled with `CONFIG_SCHEDSTATS=y` and it is enabled at `/proc/sys/kernel/sched_schedstats`

See more at https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Profiling_sleep_times.